# The WatchEvent's context doesn't reflect renaming of the directory

Tags: java, watchservice

I'm trying to implement a recursive directory watching functionality. But I found the API very hard to understand.

Let's say I have an empty directory which is the root of the directory tree I would like to watch. Now I create a new directory within this root (it's default name is 'New folder' in Windows 7) and I immediately rename it to something like 'xxx'.

The problem is when I copy a file in the new created 'xxx' directory. The WatchEvent's context is 'New folder' instead of the 'xxx'.

Here is my sscce:

```
public class Test {

    private static final String SRC_DIR = "D:/test";

    private final WatchService watcherService;

    public Test() throws IOException {
        watcherService = FileSystems.getDefault().newWatchService();
        registerDirectoryTree(Paths.get(SRC_DIR));

        startWatching();
    }

    private void startWatching() throws IOException {
        while (true) {

            WatchKey watchKey;
            try {
                watchKey = watcherService.take();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                break;
            }

            Path directory = null;
            try {
                directory = (Path) watchKey.watchable();

                for (WatchEvent<?> event : watchKey.pollEvents()) {
                    if (event.kind() == StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_CREATE) {
                        Path fileName = (Path) event.context();
                        Path filePath = directory.resolve(fileName);

                        if (Files.isDirectory(filePath, LinkOption.NOFOLLOW_LINKS)) {
                            registerDirectoryTree(filePath);

                        } else if (Files.isRegularFile(filePath, LinkOption.NOFOLLOW_LINKS)) {
                            System.out.println("Processing file. Path: " + filePath);

                        } else {
                            System.out.println("Unknown path type. Path: " + filePath);
                        }
                    }
                }
            } finally {
                boolean valid = watchKey.reset();
                if (!valid) {
                    System.out.println("Watch key is not valid. Directory: " + directory);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void registerDirectoryTree(Path sourceDir) throws IOException {
        Files.walkFileTree(sourceDir, new SimpleFileVisitor<Path>() {

            @Override
            public FileVisitResult preVisitDirectory(Path dir, BasicFileAttributes attrs) throws IOException {
                registerDirectory(dir);
                return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
            }

        });
    }

    private void registerDirectory(Path path) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("Registering watch service on " + path);
        path.register(watcherService, StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_CREATE);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        new Test();
    }

}
```

Comment: you are listening for `StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_CREATE` instead of `StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_MODIFY`.

Comment: Yes I do. When you rename a directory you get ENTRY_CREATE and not ENTRY_MODIFY Did you try the example?

Comment: i will never start anything which has `while(true)` in it - and your claim is highly unbelievable, most likely you simply dont understand how this API works.

Comment: i have just tested it - as expected you are horribly wrong - renaming directories will fire ENTRY_MODIFY but it may ALSO fire ENTRY_CREATE, thats apparently a side-effect which ... doesnt make much sense implementation-wise since the WINAPI offers distinctive, dedicated events ... apparently SUN chose to re-invent the wheel hence we're now stuck with such a weird interface